# how to upgrade the Istio v1.1.1 bundled kiali(v0.14) to v0.17?

Tags: istio, kiali

I've installed Istio v1.1.1 and Kiali v0.14 is up running. Per kiali document, Spring boot monitoring is available since v0.16. I'm trying to upgrade the kiali to latest(v0.17) by editing the kiali's deployment file(simply editting **image: docker.io/kiali/kiali:v0.14** to **v0.17**). When I try to login again, the web UI complains "The Kiali secret is missing". See the below screen shot. Actually the secret is already there.
[image]

Comment: can you pls describe your secret `kubectl describe secrets`

Comment: See also https://www.kiali.io/gettingstarted/ to get the latest Kiali

Comment: [root@izuf6dwb7yea1422h1oy3kz ~]# kubectl describe secrets/kiali -n istio-system
Name:         kiali
Namespace:    istio-system
Labels:       app=kiali
Annotations:
Type:         Opaque

Data
====
passphrase:  8 bytes
username:    5 bytes

Comment: @YoufaMao , as Lucas said, it is certainly not a safe way to upgrade Kiali by just updating the image tag, as you could miss changes in the yaml files. I'd recommend using the install steps from my previous comment.

Comment: I think that's a common error, that sometimes pops up. Try deleting the secret and creating it again.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the 0.17 deployment descriptor too ?

https://github.com/kiali/kiali/blob/v0.17.0/deploy/kubernetes/deployment.yaml

Note that between versions config might be changed, so just upgrading the image could be not enough.

Comment: we've successfully applied the 0.17 deployment descriptors. thanks!